# How to remove milliseconds from LocalTime in java 8

Tags: java, rounding, datetime-format, java-time, localtime

Using the java.time framework, I want to print time in format `hh:mm:ss`, but `LocalTime.now()` gives the time in the format `hh:mm:ss,nnn`. I tried to use `DateTimeFormatter`:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME;
LocalTime time = LocalTime.now();
String f = formatter.format(time);
System.out.println(f);
```

The result:

```
22:53:51.894
```

How can I remove milliseconds from the time?

Comment: Use a different formatter?

Comment: there are no nanoseconds in your example, and even IF there were such a precision shown : within most operating systems time-precisions below 1ms make no sense / are literally impossible, all you get is somewhat random noise, expressed in numbers.
You can COUNT PROCESSOR-TICKS, though ...

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Edit: I should add that these are nanoseconds not milliseconds.

I feel these answers don't really answer the question using the Java 8 SE Date and Time API as intended.  I believe the truncatedTo method is the solution here.

```
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
System.out.println("Pre-Truncate:  " + now);
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME;
System.out.println("Post-Truncate: " + now.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS).format(dtf));
```

Output:

```
Pre-Truncate:  2015-10-07T16:40:58.349
Post-Truncate: 2015-10-07T16:40:58
```

Alternatively, if using Time Zones:

```
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
ZonedDateTime zoned = now.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Denver"));
System.out.println("Pre-Truncate:  " + zoned);
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME;
System.out.println("Post-Truncate: " + zoned.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS).format(dtf));
```

Output:

```
Pre-Truncate:  2015-10-07T16:38:53.900-06:00[America/Denver]
Post-Truncate: 2015-10-07T16:38:53-06:00
```

Comment: This confused me because I'm used to calling parse on a formatter object, instead of a static parse method on the type of object I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 41):

cut to minutes:

```
 localTime.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
```

cut to seconds:

```
localTime.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS);
```

Example:

```java
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

LocalTime.now()
  .truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS)
  .format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME);
```

Outputs `15:07:25`

Comment: Thanks! I added example to show that the formatter will honor the truncation, that's great, and it works just the same with `ZonedDateTime`.

Answer (score 11):

Just create the `DateTimeFormatter` explicitly:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
LocalTime time = LocalTime.now();
String f = formatter.format(time);
System.out.println(f);
```

(I prefer to explicitly use the US locale, to make it clear that I *don't* want anything from the default format locale.)

Answer (score 5):

Use this in your first line

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use patterns defined here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

For example:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy MM dd HH. mm. ss");
String text = date.toString(formatter);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can so it simply by using regex on the string:

```
String f = formatter.format(time).replaceAll("\\.[^.]*", "");
```

This deletes (by replacing with blank) the last dot and everything after.

Comment: I think this is more like a hack

Comment: @Shervin why is it a "hack"? It's a formatting problem, with a formatting solution. In a way it's superior to writing your own format pattern, because you don't need to know anything about the pattern or how to write one for this to work.